# ref.listen in Riverpod flutter

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have this error message

> The argument type 'StateProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProviderListenable<StateController>'.

And, this is my provider code

```
final loginExceptionProvider = StateProvider<LoginException>((ref) {
  return const LoginException(message: 'ok');
});
```

and this my ref.listen code

```
 ref.listen<StateController<LoginException>>(loginExceptionProvider, ( prev, next) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('yoyo')));
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The provider doesn't expose a `StateController<T>` but simply `T`

The correct syntax would be:

```dart
ref.listen<LoginException>(loginExceptionProvider, (prev, next) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
    .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('yoyo')));
});
```

Comment: what is the difference between notifier and state? loginExceptionProvider.notifier and loginExceptionProvider.state

Comment: Same problem, tried this solution, but something is not okey, can you please check my question out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73015349/riverpod-listen-not-getting-called-after-statenotifier-changed

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer in this link
[Riverpod Documentation](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/)

I just add the notifier on provider

```
 ref.listen<StateController<LoginException>>(loginExceptionProvider.notifier, ( prev, next) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('yoyo')));
    });
```