# Riverpod listen not getting called after statenotifier changed

Tags: flutter, state, listener, provider, riverpod

I built an app, where the User can select his location, and we will show the nearby available items.

```
 class LocationState {   LatLng? location;
 
   LocationState({this.location});
 
   LocationState copyWith({LatLng? location}) =>
       LocationState(location: location); }
 
 class CurrentLocationNotifier extends StateNotifier<LocationState> {  
 CurrentLocationNotifier(LocationState state) : super(state);
 
   void changeLocation(LatLng? location) {
     print("new location state");
     print(location);
     state = state.copyWith(location: location);   } }
 
 final currentLocationProvider =
     StateNotifierProvider<CurrentLocationNotifier, LocationState?>((ref) {   return
 CurrentLocationNotifier(LocationState()); });
```

The print inside the notifier will be called, when I select the new address:

```
 ... return AppCard(
       onTap: () {
         userVM.selectDefaultAddress(address: address);
         locationNotifier.changeLocation(address.location);
       }, ...
```

Inside the page, where I would like to listen for the location changes, so I can fetch the data again, won't triggered:

```
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

class UserHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const UserHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final homeState = ref.watch(homeVMProvider);
    final userState = ref.watch(userVMProvider);
    final homeVM = ref.read(homeVMProvider.notifier);

    ref.listen<LocationState?>(currentLocationProvider, (previous, current) {
  print("not getting called");
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(content: Text('Location changed $current')),
  );
  homeVM.init();
});
```

I already checked this post: [ref.listen in Riverpod flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69991845/ref-listen-in-riverpod-flutter), Rémi helped there, but it does not seems to working for me

I am using:
**riverpod: ^2.0.0-dev.9
hooks_riverpod: ^2.0.0-dev.9**

This demo worked: https://github.com/aspiiire/riverpod-ref.listen-part8/blob/main/lib/main.dart

So maybe the issue is with the new version?

Comment: Where does locationNotifier in onTap come from?

Comment: You should try to replace LocationState? -> LocationState